# Trying to get a regex to recognize and extract words from both camelCase and CamelCase

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this halfway working. This works great:

```
'MyOwnVar'.match(/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/g)
```

Result:

```
["My", "Own", "Var"]
```

The goal is to pull out the individual words. But if I pass a camelCase name to it:

```
'myOwnVar'.match(/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/g)
```

I get:

```
["myOwn", "Var"]
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. As far as I can tell, two sets of `()` should store the matching results in two separate array elements. It's lumping them in together for some reason.

Comment: `.match(/([A-Za-z][a-z]+)/g)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I have understood the question properly the following regex should do the trick:

```
/([A-Za-z][a-z]+)/g
```

In case that a single character (as "m" in "mOwnVariable") should be considered as a *word*:

```
/([A-Za-z][a-z]*)/g
```

Comment: Your last edit was better, that considered a var like `XMyVar` and would separate 'X' as its own word.

Comment: @Vohuman nice approach with the first `[A-Za-z]`. At first I thought of an overcomplicated pattern. It proves simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/([A-Z]?[a-z]+)/g
```

See regex explanation https://regex101.com/r/zS8vJ3/1

```js
// For camelCase
var matches = 'myOwnVar'.match(/([A-Z]?[a-z]+)/g);
document.write('// For camelCase<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 2) + '</pre>');


// For CamelCase
var matches = 'MyOwnVar'.match(/([A-Z]?[a-z]+)/g);
document.write('<hr /> // For CamelCase <pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Result: `["myOwnVar"]`

Comment: @ffxsam Isn't that what you want? To match camelCase words

Comment: No, see above. I'm trying to extract each word.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that grouping with `()` does not store the separate groups in different array elements. Matching with `(ab)(cd)` will always output the same as `(abcd)`.

Now unless the situation is more complicated than you're letting on, simply `/([A-Z]*[a-z]+)/g` will do.

```js
var result = 'MyOwnVar'.match(/([A-Z]*[a-z]+)/g);
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = result.join();

result = 'myOwnVar'.match(/([A-Z]*[a-z]+)/g);
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = result.join();
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

For other situations, for instance input like `HTMLContent`, see the other answer(s).

Comment: Isn't `[A-Z]?` better than `[A-Z]*`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    'MyOwnVar'.match(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)/g)

    'myOwnVar'.match(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)/g)
```